# как выделить память под двумерный массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы, выделение-памяти

Мне нужно кроме того, что выделить, понять как передавать его в функции для перемножения матриц. Вернее код для этого уже написан, но больше 500 элементов в массиве кидает ошибку сегментации(возможно не 500 а больше, но при 800 ошибка). Мне нужно отправлять в функции и потом снова получать в общем. А то я видел пример, вроде выделяется , но как потом обе меры передавать в функцию и работать с ними. Например  с элементом 2:2 или всеми элементами сразу.

Comment: я передаю по ссылке в основном.

Comment: я передавал так a]

Comment: Для начала вам стоит определить причину ошибки. А вообще в языке нет поддержки двухмерных массивов. Можно выделить массив указателей на массивы данных. Или один массив и приделать к нему индексирование.

Comment: Массивы - понятие растяжимое. Куча вариантов исполнения. Приведите фактическое исполнение массива - посмотрим.

Comment: Покажите код, который у вас уже есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял, что у меня уже был ответ, просто я неправильно передавал.
 Все работает!
 Мне не пришлось ничего менять в самой программе, только правильно передать надо было:

```
/*выделяем количество строк в массиве*/
double **a = new double *[800];
/*выделяем количество столбцов в массиве*/
for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
  a[i] = new double [800];
}
/*выделяем количество строк в массиве*/
double **b = new double *[800];
/*выделяем количество столбцов в массиве*/
for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
  b[i] = new double [800];
}

matrix(a, kolstolbcov1, kolstrok1); //передаю a
matrix(b, kolstolbcov2, kolstrok2); //передаю b

//функцию создал как void matrix(double **a, int kolstolbcov, int kolstrok) 
//void matrix(double **b, int kolstolbcov2, int kolstrok2)


for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
  delete []a[i];
}
delete []a;

for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
  delete []b[i];
}
delete []b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Выделяете память нужного размера. Дальше переводите в тип двумерной матрицы.

```
// g++ -Wall mass.cpp
# include <iostream>

void f(double * arr,size_t width,size_t height){
  double (*matrix)[width][height] = (double (*)[width][height])arr;
  // или так на ваш вкус
  //double (*matrix)[height][width] = (double (*)[height][width])arr;
  (*matrix)[3][5] = 10 ;  }

int main(){
  size_t const width = 30 ;
  size_t const height = 30 ;
  double * arr = new double[width * height];
  f(arr,width,height);
  double (*matrix)[width][height] = (double (*)[width][height])arr;
  std::cout<<"(*matrix)[3][5]="<<(*matrix)[3][5];
  delete[]arr;}
```

Comment: Вопрос помечен тэгом [C++]. Ваше `double (*massiv)[width][height]` внутри `f` допустимо только в С. В С++ ничего подобного нет.

Comment: @AnT Уупсс ... Всю жизнь программлю и не знал, что так нельзя. Попробуйте другим компилятором, вдруг это правда, что только в Linux можно.

Comment: Это не имеет никакого отношения к Linux. Это возможно в компиляторе `g++`. Но компилятор `g++ ` не является компилятором языка С++, пока вы не укажете в командной строке как минимум ключи `-std=...` и `-pedantic`.

Comment: @AnT `warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘massiv’ [-Wvla]`. Нууу тогда напишем свой класс.